# Angular Resolve Not Loading

Tags: angularjs

Angular 1.6, ui.router issue. I am running into an issue with the resolve of a state. Anytime I put in the resolve feature into the $stateProvider nothing in my view renders. If I comment out just the resolve portion, my bids variable shows up in the view with the hardcoded values.

It looks like /bids.json has the data I need because if I run `console.log($http.get('/sales.json'))` without the resolve state, in my controller, it returns the following:

> $$state: Object > value: Object > data: Array[2] > 0: Object
>   amount:"45342" currency:"USD"

Where is the error in the code below?

```
angular.module('salesApp', ['ui.router', 'templates'])
.config([
'$locationProvider',
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({ 
    enabled: false
  });
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

  $stateProvider
    .state('sales', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      resolve: { //whenever I enable this, nothing renders in view
        postPromise: ['sales', function(salesReturned){
            var al = salesReturned.getSales('/sales.json');
        }]
      }
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])

.factory('sales', ['$http', function($http){
  var o = {
    sales:[
        {currency: 'USD', amount: 5},
        {currency: 'USD', amount: 5}
    ]
  };
  o.getSales = function(JSONurl) { 
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: JSONurl}).success(function(data){
      angular.copy(data, o.sales);
    });
  };
  return o;
}])

.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'sales',
    '$http',
    function($scope, sales, $http){
      $scope.sales = sales.sales; 
    }
])
```

Comment: `postPromise` doesn't return anything

Comment: I am confused, when I uncomment the resolve containing the 'postPromise' nothing is rendered in the angular view, not even `<h1>hello</h1>` If I take it out then a hello world and the hard coded `bids` variable renders

Comment: The router is waiting for your promise to resolve with a value before rendering the state's view. You aren't returning a resolved value, so it never renders

Comment: Also, your `sales` provider doesn't have a `getBids` method

Comment: Found answer below. Code was right per angular 1.5. However, I was using 1.6. We should upvote, it could save some major headaches..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will save people some headaches: `.success(function(data)` has been deprecated in angular 1.6. Need to use `.then(function successCallback(response)` instead per: new [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 0):

The resolve property `postPromise` is an array.  This looks odd to me.  It should probably read:

```
postPromise: function(bidsReturned){
    return bidsReturned.getBids('/bids.json');
}
```

If you are passing in the array to ensure the code works correctly after minify then you should probably use a different technique. See examples [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki).

Comment: Implemented your suggestions, still didn't work. This resolve technique is based on: https://thinkster.io/tutorials/angular-rails/wiring-everything-up. It's odd because I have gotten a different app on angular 1.5 to work this way, but for some reason this one is failing out..

Comment: Create a codepen or plnkr that demonstrates your issue.  Then we can help better.

Comment: This answer will fail minification. OP was using the DI annotation correctly

Comment: Correct - It will fail minification but we are trying to narrow down on the cause of the problem.  Actually taking a look at with fresh eyes.  It's obvious.  The function isn't returning anything.